# SQL: convert column items to new fields

Tags: sql, pivot, mariadb

I have the following `table1`:

```
FieldA      FieldB  FieldC
--------------------------
mario       carta        5
mario       plastica     5
francesco   plastica    10
mario       plastica     5
giovanni    carta        2
```

And I would like to get the following `table2` with a SQL query:

```
FieldA   carta    plastica
--------------------------
mario       5           10
francesco   0           10
giovanni    2            0
```

This means that each item of `FieldB` has to be converted to a new field of `table2`. Then, the item of the new fields has to be the sum of `FieldC` but I know how to do this.

The question is about how to convert `FieldB` items to new fields in another table.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Is that separate columns, or one column with ; separated data? BTW, tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: found it! it is mariadb :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT FieldA,
       SUM(CASE WHEN FieldB = 'carta' THEN FieldC ELSE 0 END) AS carta,
       SUM(CASE WHEN FieldB = 'plastica' THEN FieldC ELSE 0 END) AS plastica
FROM table1
GROUP BY FieldA
```

This query will work on [Oracle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/09158/1), [MySQL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb69ba/1), [PostgreSQL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/893d7/1) and [SQL Server](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/893d7/1) and most other variants...

Comment: I cannot use that. I cannot know in the query which items are in FieldB. thanks

Comment: @Stefano that can be resolved, but does depend on which dbms you are using?

Comment: it is mariadb :)

Comment: So how many different values are possible in the `FieldB` column?

Comment: I cannot know at prior. It could be 2 or 100. And it can change every time.

Comment: Unfortunately MariaDB doesn't have a PIVOT command so you would need to use dynamic SQL (see [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/pivoting-in-mariadb/) mariadb knowledge base article). It would almost certainly be easier to implement in your application code.

Comment: @Nick . . . The `COALESCE()` is superfluous.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah... a bit of overkill! Thanks for pointing it out, I've removed it.